# Simple CSS Keyframe doesnt take effect

Tags: css

I want to make an infinite ripple effect and it should work fine, but thats not the case. For some reason the keyframe functions dont seem to have effect. What I am missing?

```css
 /* CUSTOM CSS */

.rippler {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 160px auto;
  -webkit-animation: ripple 0.6s linear infinite;
  border-radius: 100px;
    background: blue;
}

@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(blue, 0.1),
                0 0 0 20px rgba(blue, 0.1),
                0 0 0 60px rgba(blue, 0.1),
                0 0 0 100px rgba(blue, 0.1);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(blue, 0.1),
                0 0 0 60px rgba(blue, 0.1),
                0 0 0 100px rgba(blue, 0.1),
                0 0 0 140px rgba(blue, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="rippler"></span>
```

A pretty similar code is working fine: https://codepen.io/jaguar66/pen/RrWjZp?editors=1100

Comment: Vendor prefixes are not needed anymore in the latest browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation#browser_compatibility

Comment: Your animation is working fine (you can test it if you change something obvious like the width or height). The problem is probably that your `box-shadow` isn't displayed as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're wrongly using the `rgba` function. That function expects 4 parameters: `red`, `green`, `blue` and `opacity` where the first **3** act as the values for the `RGB` color system which must be a valid integer between `0` and `255` and the last parameter must be a valid number between `0` and `1` (fractions are allowed in the `opacity` parameter).
In your case you are sending only **2** parameters which is wrong. The fix is simple, just send the `blue` color as `RGB` values like so: `rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)`.

Here's a working example:

```css
/* CUSTOM CSS */

.rippler {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 160px auto;
  -webkit-animation: ripple 0.6s linear infinite;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1),
                0 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1), 
                0 0 0 60px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1),
                0 0 0 100px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1),
                0 0 0 60px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1),
                0 0 0 100px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1),
                0 0 0 140px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="rippler"></span>
```

> The explanation above is a brief description of the `rgba` function. I recommend learning more about the [`rgba()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/rgba) function on MDN.

> **Note:** Vendor prefixes are no longer needed with the `animation` rule nor the `keyframes` declaration.